# Using microdata itemprop and itemtype for non-English websites

Tags: microdata, internationalization

How should I use microdata `itemprop` and `itemtype` for non-English websites? Is there a way to define vocabulary for non-English websites, and what `itemprop` values can be used? Are `itemprop` values self defined or some vocabulary must be defined first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microdata vocabularies are usually language-independent.

Take for example the vocabulary [schema.org](http://schema.org/): a [`Movie`](http://schema.org/Movie) can have the property [`alternativeHeadline`](http://schema.org/alternativeHeadline). The expected type is *Text*, and it’s defined as: "A secondary title of the CreativeWork.". It doesn’t matter at all if this secondary title is in English, German, or Sindarin.

---

> Are `itemprop` values self defined or some vocabulary must be defined first?

You don’t *have* to use a "defined" vocabulary at all. But then don’t expect your Microdata annotations to be of any use to someone else. So typically you’ll want to use defined (well-known) vocabularies. See http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/#selecting-names-when-defining-vocabularies.

> i want to use translations form english to my language. So for example 'Movie' is translated 'Film'...So it is absolutely ok to use itemprop values on my language?

Let’s take `http://schema.org/Movie` as example. If you want to annotate your content with the schema.org vocabulary, and you have a movie/film, you *have* to use exactly this URL. It’s an identifier, not a description itself (it could have been named `http://schema.org/78161`, too. They only used English terms in the URL because of convenience).

If you’d use `http://schema.org/Film` (**don’t use this!**), it wouldn’t have the same meaning. Also, you should never mint new URLs which you don’t control yourself.

So you should use your own domain, e.g. `http://yourdomain.example.org/Film`. You can use this, yes. But then you have your own vocabulary, which has nothing to do with schema.org.

All this is similar to HTML element names. For example, you use the `address` element in every language, not only on English pages. It wouldn’t make sense (and it isn’t allowed) to translate `<address></address>` element to `<адреса></адреса>`.

Comment: I am interested to know this because i want to use terms in my language, Serbian. I don't intend to use some self defined words, i have explained it badly, i want to use translations form english to my language. So for example 'Movie' is translated 'Film'...So it is absolutely ok to use itemprop values on my language?

Comment: @Dušan: See my answer edit. If you are translating `itemprop` values, you are using something else (= your own vocabulary).